# Recommendations for beginner piano pieces that make equal use of both hands

Tags: piano, practice, hand-independence

There are more demands on my right hand for much of what I play, and am beginning to notice a difference between my hands when playing e.g. scales.

I would like to play more pieces that make equal usage of both hands. For example, [Bach's Minuet in A Minor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-v5tAtl2KjQ) does a pretty good job. I think many of Bach's inventions also make equal usage—but, right now, they're above my level.

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Answer (score 4):

The Bach Minuet in A Minor comes from the Anna Magdalena Notebook ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notebook_for_Anna_Magdalena_Bach)), which contains many pieces of a similar level. Many, if not all, of those pieces are [available at IMSLP](https://imslp.org/wiki/Notebook_for_Anna_Magdalena_Bach_(Bach,_Johann_Sebastian)).

You could also try the collection, *Introduction to Classics to Moderns*, edited by Denes Agay. It contains pieces from the pre-Baroque through the mid-twentieth century, all of which use both hands equally (except the very first song). The pieces are placed in approximate order of difficulty.